# Example of Kerberos Auth?

Tags: afnetworking

Our service moved from digest auth to SPNEGO/Kerberos and I'm having trouble finding much on the internet about kerberos & NSURL*.  Is there any support for Kerberos auth in AFNetworking?  My basic understanding is I'd need to NSTask out to kinit and get a ticket, then create some kind of NSURLCredential encapsulating my KerberosServiceTicket?

My inability to find much on google tells me I'm missing something fundamental with this stack, where should I be looking?

I want to authenticate all traffic going through my AFHTTPClient with a kerberos ticket.